# In django, for a user, get all objects which ForeignKey to groups he/she belongs to (efficiently)

Tags: django, querying

I have 3 models, User, Group and Exam:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group

class Exam(models.Model):
    # a lot of fields
    solutions_group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
```

For an instance `user` of model `User` I want to get all `Exam`s in whose `solutions_group` `user` belongs.

This is what I thought of:

```
exam_list = []
for group in user.groups.all():
    exam_list+= list(group.exam_set.all())
```

But this involves multiple database queries.

Is there a better way to do this, involving lesses queries?

I'm using Python 3.4 and Django 1.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try filtering on `Exam.objects` using an ["in" filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#in)

```
user_groups = user.groups.all()
user_exams = Exam.objects.filter(solutions_group__in=user_groups)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also use the related_name from group to user (user_set) using the following query:

```
user_exams = Exam.objects.filter(solutions_group__user_set=user)
```

Comment: `Exam.objects.filter(solutions_group__user_set=admin)` didn't work. `ValueError: Cannot query "admin": Must be "Group" instance.` Here admin is of type User.

Comment: `Exam.objects.filter(solutions_group__user_set=user)` didn't work. `ValueError: Cannot query "gauss": Must be "Group" instance.` Here "gauss" is `user.username`